# MouseHover and Click events in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do the following events using `Selenium` `WebDriver`

- `Mousehover` to Create Application and then
- `Click` on the New Application

I have following code , the below is a `function`

```
public Boolean entermousehoverandclick(String mousehovervalue , String clickvalue)
{
    Boolean status = true;
    try
    {
        WebElement create = driver.findElement(By.linkText(mousehovervalue));

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(create).pause(1000).build().perform();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.linkText(clickvalue));

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        status = false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

I am calling the above function in the testcase as below

```
if(fn.entermousehoverandclick("Create", "New Application"))
   {
   System.out.println("Successfully clicked on create application");
   }
  else
   {
  System.out.println("Error in clicking create application");                   
   }
```

While running the test case, the script clicks on the create option but it is not selecting the new application option.

Could you please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: change this `driver.findElement(By.linkText(clickvalue));` to this `driver.findElement(By.linkText(clickvalue)).click();`

Comment: Thank you very much Saurabh Gaur , now the script is running. I am able to mousehover and click on the new application.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest you remove those .sleep()s and replace them with WebDriverWait. It will make your script more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your `entermousehoverandclick` function, you are going to find **"New Application"** link but you are not performing any action here. you need to call `.click()` after successfully find the link **"New Application"** as below :-

```
WebElement newApplication = driver.findElement(By.linkText(clickvalue));
newApplication.click();
```

Hope it will help you..:)